# Images not displaying in pdf when using Grover gem in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html-to-pdf, grover

I'm trying to generate a pdf that includes an image using the [Grover gem](https://github.com/Studiosity/grover) in Ruby on Rails. The image displays properly in html but when I convert the page to pdf the image does not display.

My images are stored in S3 and are displayed in the pdf with the following code:

```
<%= image_tag b.main_image, class: "cover-image" %>
```

Everything else works just fine.

Has anyone else run into issues displaying images with Grover.

Comment: What are you using to generate the PDF's?

Comment: If you're using wkhtml-to-pdf you will need to use different tag conditionally - https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf#wicked_pdf-helpers